# Flutter persistent navigation bar with named routes?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been searching around for a good navigation/router example for Flutter but I have not managed to find one.

What I want to achieve is very simple:

1. Persistent bottom navigation bar that highlights the current top level route
2. Named routes so I can navigate to any route from anywhere inside the app
3. Navigator.pop should always take me to the previous view I was in

The official Flutter demo for BottomNavigationBar achieves 1 but back button and routing dont't work. Same problem with PageView and TabView. There are many other tutorials that achieve 2 and 3 by implementing MaterialApp routes but none of them seem to have a persistent navigation bar.

Are there any examples of a navigation system that would satisfy all these requirements?

Comment: did you find any solution for your question?

Comment: @Daniel.V No I didn't. I ended up using BottomNavigationBar to achieve 1, ditched requirement no. 2 and manually handled pop so that I could always navigate back to the root view of the current tab. The open source scene has evolved since then so there might be new libraries that might achieve at least 1 and 2.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

All of your 3 requirements can be achieved by using a custom [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

The Flutter team did a [video](https://youtu.be/EcAwFpC9S8s) on this, and the article they followed is here: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

Basically, you will need to wrap the body of your Scaffold in a custom `Navigator`:

```dart
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          // Manage your route names here
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => HomePage();
              break;
            case '/page1':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page1();
              break;
            case '/page2':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page2();
              break;
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
          // You can also return a PageRouteBuilder and
          // define custom transitions between pages
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Within your bottom navigation bar, to navigate to a new screen in the new custom `Navigator`, you just have to call this:

```dart
_navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/yourRouteName');
```

To achieve the 3rd requirement, which is `Navigator.pop` taking you to the previous view, you will need to wrap the custom `Navigator` with a `WillPopScope`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
          _navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Navigator(
        // ...
      ),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavigationBar,
  );
}
```

And that should be it! No need to manually handle pop or manage a custom history list.

Comment: How to keep alive every tab. In above method each page is recreated when move to next tab/bottomNavigationItem.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan You shouldn't need to. Just separate state from UI. Some useful library options: Redux, BLoC, MobX.

Comment: @czx How to hide the bottom navigation bar in sub routes?

Comment: Is there a way that you could also use this from the very top level? I use flutter for web and this kind of navigation does not work from the url tab sadly.

Comment: @CZX
I don't really get it. This solution implies that Homepage(), Page1() and Page2() must not return Scaffolds themselves because one does not want to have nested Scaffolds. But what if my Widgets return Scaffolds, e.g. because they have Floating Action Button?

Comment: This works, but for some reason I get massive lag from it., has anyone else experience this?

Comment: `No need to manually handle pop or manage a custom history list` - it's need, becasue bottom nav has currentIndex and you need manage it on every pop, push.

Comment: @Janne Annala I think he means that `builder = newPage()`  will create a new page on every switch, since it's calling the constructor

Answer (score 6):

[CupertinoTabBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html) behave exactly same as you described, but in iOS style. It can be [used in `MaterialApps`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7508#issuecomment-337182525) however.

[Sample Code](https://github.com/xster/flutter-test/blob/master/t48_material_and_cupertino/lib/main.dart)

Comment: The link to CupertinoTabBar is 404. Try this instead: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for would violate the [material design specification](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior).

> On Android, the Back button does not navigate between bottom
>   navigation bar views.

A navigation drawer would give you 2 and 3, but not 1. It depends on what's more important to you.

You could try using LocalHistoryRoute. This achieves the effect you want:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return new MainPageState();
  }
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<int> _history = [0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Bottom Nav Back'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('Page $_currentIndex'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.touch_app),
            title: new Text('keypad'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.assessment),
            title: new Text('chart'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cloud),
            title: new Text('weather'),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (int index) {
          _history.add(index);
          setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
          Navigator.push(context, new BottomNavigationRoute()).then((x) {
            _history.removeLast();
            setState(() => _currentIndex = _history.last);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigationRoute extends LocalHistoryRoute<void> {}
```

Comment: This is something I want to achieve even if it violates some arbitrary design rule. Even the official Youtube app navigate between bottom nav bar views when pressing the back button. Same goes for Spotify and pretty much all big apps out there.

Comment: Each tap push a Navigation stack, but never removed.

Comment: They are removed by the Android back button, as requested by the question.

Comment: I got it working by extending `Route` instead of `LocalHistoryRoute`

Comment: On Android, hitting the back button in an activity containing a BottomNavigationBar should pop to the first index (first page) & hitting the back button again should finish the activity.