# How to persist BottomNavigationBar when using Flutter navigation and routes

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation

I'm making a project with 4 different pages. I use a "BottomNavigationBar" widget to navigate to each page. When an icon in the "BottomNavigationBar" is pressed, I display a different page in the Scaffold body. I don't use any routing so when a user presses back on Android, the app closes. Something I don't want happening.

All the guides I have found reload the whole "Scaffold" when navigating, but I want to only update the "body" property of the "Scaffold" widget. When a `Navigation.pop()` occurs I again only want the "Scaffold" body to change.

I have found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681415/flutter-persistent-navigation-bar-with-named-routes) around the same issue, but the answer didn't work for me.

Another workaround I can try is making a custom history list, that I then update when pages are changed. Catching OnWillPop event to update the pages when the back button is pressed. I haven't tried this because I feel like there has to be a better way.

The Scaffold widget that displays the page.

```dart
  Widget createScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: EmptyAppBar(),
      body: _displayedPage,
      bottomNavigationBar: createBottomNavigationbar(),
    );
  }
```

The BottomNavigationBar widget.

```dart
  Widget createBottomNavigationbar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home,
              color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor),
          title: new Text('Home',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color:
                  _selectedIndex == 0 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor)),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.show_chart,
              color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor),
          title: new Text('Month',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color:
                  _selectedIndex == 1 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor)),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.history,
                color: _selectedIndex == 2 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor),
            title: Text('History',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: _selectedIndex == 2
                        ? selectedColor
                        : unselectedColor))),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings,
                color: _selectedIndex == 3 ? selectedColor : unselectedColor),
            title: Text('Settings',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: _selectedIndex == 3
                        ? selectedColor
                        : unselectedColor)))
      ],
    );
  }
```

Methods that update the state of the displayed page.

```dart
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _changeDisplayedScreen(index);

    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });

  }

  void _changeDisplayedScreen(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        setState(() {
          _displayedPage = new LatestReadingPage();
        });
        break;
      case 1:
        setState(() {
          _displayedPage = new HomeScreen();
          //Placeholder
        });
        break;
      case 2:
        setState(() {
          _displayedPage = new HomeScreen();
          //Placeholder
        });
        break;
      case 3:
        setState(() {
          _displayedPage = new HomeScreen();
          //Placeholder
        });
        break;
      default:
        setState(() {
          _displayedPage = new LatestReadingPage();
        });
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to be able to use the Flutter Navigation infrastructure, but only update the body property of the Scaffold widget when changing pages. Instead of the whole screen.

A lot like the Youtube app or Google news app.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: Not really, I implemented a workaround. I catch the "back" event and I maintain a custom history list. Which I then update when the page is changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have added an answer to the post that you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59133502/6064621

The answer below is similar to the one above, but I've also added unknown routes here:

---

What you want can be achieved by using a custom [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

The Flutter team did a [video](https://youtu.be/EcAwFpC9S8s) on this, and the article they followed is here: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

Basically, you will need to wrap the body of your Scaffold in a custom `Navigator`:

```dart
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          // Manage your route names here
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => HomePage();
              break;
            case '/page1':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page1();
              break;
            case '/page2':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page2();
              break;
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
          // You can also return a PageRouteBuilder and
          // define custom transitions between pages
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Within your bottom navigation bar, to navigate to a new screen in the new custom `Navigator`, you just have to call this:

```dart
_navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/yourRouteName');
```

If you don't used named routes, then here is what you should do for your custom `Navigator`, and for navigating to new screens:

```dart
// Replace the above onGenerateRoute function with this one
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => YourHomePage(),
    settings: settings,
  );
},
```

```dart
_navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => YourNextPage(),
));
```

To let `Navigator.pop` take you to the previous view, you will need to wrap the custom `Navigator` with a `WillPopScope`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
          _navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Navigator(
        // ...
      ),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavigationBar,
  );
}
```

And that should be it! No need to manually handle pop too much or manage a custom history list.

Comment: Glad to have stumble upon this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your body inside the IndexedStack widget. Like this:

```
body: IndexedStack(
      index: selectedIndex,
      children: _children, //define a  widget children list
    ),
```

Here's a link https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: EmptyAppBar(),
      body: _displayedPage[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: _createBottomNavigationbar,
    );
```

Then you make a widget list of all the Screens you want:

```
List<Widget> _displayedPage = [LatestReadingPage(), HomeScreen(), ExampleScreen()];
```

Comment: This will work iff your `_displayedPage` 'List' contains stateless widgets.