# PageView vs Routing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, uipageviewcontroller, flutter-pageview, named-routing

I am new to Flutter and cannot find many info about best practice about: when to use Raouting and when to use PageView.

In my app i want to have shared ApBar and BottomNavigation also i want to have details page in some pages.
Should i use PageView or Routinbg for BottomNavigation click.
If i use PageView then how i would use child routes for details page?

I understand it is quite wide topic but i would appreciate if somebody can share good reading about it or share his experience

Comment: You can do same thing with pageview and route pages. It's about how you design ur app.  You can move from pageview to details page using route..

Comment: it is depend on the UI which you want to implement. If you want to use tabs then u should go for the PagerView.

Comment: Thanks.
Maybe you will have an answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610269/cannot-make-bottom-navigation-bar-and-routing-work-together-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment108987788_61610269