# Navigation with custom navigator and globalkey

Tags: flutter

I did what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681415/flutter-persistent-navigation-bar-with-named-routes/59133502#59133502) for a persistent bottom bar using a custom navigator.

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          // Manage your route names here
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => HomePage();
              break;
            case '/page1':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page1();
              break;
            case '/page2':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => Page2();
              break;
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
          // You can also return a PageRouteBuilder and
          // define custom transitions between pages
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Now, if I have child widgets on HomePage with a button that needs to navigate me to a Page2, How would I achieve that from inside HomePage - because?

Comment: like in any other `Navigator`: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2')`

Comment: Yup that worked.. I don't know why I was thinking I had to pass `_navigatorKey`. Thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

some button or GestureDetector
`onTap : ()=>Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2')`
or
`onPress : ()=>Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page2')`